# Changing the orientation of a phase label in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, label, orientation

In Visio, is it possible to change the orientation of a phase label from vertical to horizontal? I see where under Cross-Functional Flowchart I can rotate the swimlane labels from horizontal to vertical but I want to rotate the phase label from vertical to horizontal.

Comment: Which version of Visio?